# How do I get the class hierarchy of list or set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For a collection abstract base class (e.g. MutableSequence), I can do the following to get its class hierarchy:

```
from typing import MutableSequence

MutableSequence.mro()
```

How do I do the same for `list` or `set`?

Trying `list.mro()` just returns `[list, object]`. Does this mean that `list` is totally unrelated to `MutableSequence`, for example?

Comment: Looks like you answered your question yourself

Comment: I guess...why is `list` totally unrelated to `MutableSequence` then? It would make sense that they're part of the same hierarchy?

Comment: I actually think that it would make sense if `list` inherited from a bunch of classes in `typing` or `collections.abc`. Maybe `list` is just so fundamental that its MRO must be as short as possible so that its methods could be resolved as quickly as possible.

Comment: FYI: Everything from `collections.abc` (including `MutableSequence`) uses a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks) that overrides the behavior for things like `isinstance` and `issubclass`.  So to answer your question, yes, `list` is totally unrelated to `MutableSequence` in its implementation.

Comment: @0x5453 Ah, I suppose that's how mypy lets one put a list in a parameter that expects, say a `MutableSequence`. @ForceBru that sounds like a good hypothesis.